# Unable to add appendchild function to property in the Object

Tags: javascript, dom

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script text="type/javascript">
      var countdown=function()
{
         // create a couple of elements in an otherwise empty HTML page
         this .heading=document.createElement("h1");
         this .heading_text=document.createTextNode("Big Head!");
         this .heading.appendChild(heading_text);
         this .document.body.appendChild(heading);
 }
var obj1 = new countdown();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above code I am unable to add `appendChild(heading_text)` to the heading_text property and facing error

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: heading_text is not defined".

How to proceed with this program.?

Comment: remove space after `this`

Comment: remove `this .` each time it occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because `this.heading_text` exists and `heading_text` doesn't

make it

```
var countdown=function()
   {
         // create a couple of elements in an otherwise empty HTML page
         var heading=document.createElement("h1");
         var heading_text=document.createTextNode("Big Head!");
         heading.appendChild(heading_text);
         document.body.appendChild(heading);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks @BhojendraNepal

Answer (score 0):

you are declaring variables in wrong way..

declaring a variable in js is like this

```
var variable;
```

so, in your script change these lines:

```
this .heading=document.createElement("h1");
this .heading_text=document.createTextNode("Big Head!");
this .heading.appendChild(heading_text);
this .document.body.appendChild(heading);
```

into this:

```
var heading=document.createElement("h1");
var heading_text=document.createTextNode("Big Head!");
heading.appendChild(heading_text);
document.body.appendChild(heading);
```